# how to disable datePicker's autofill feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using datepicker (datepicker.min.js) in my JSP. 
http://freqdec.github.io/datePicker/

When I input 01/01/17, it will automatically fill it as 01/01/2017 in chrome and 01/01/1917 in IE.

Does anybody know how to disable this feature?

I hope that I input 01/01/17 and get 01/01/17 instead of 01/01/2017 or 01/01/1917.

Comment: Please provide a link to the library.
There are several libraries that are called datepicker.

Comment: What is feature should be disabled? How must datepicker work?

Comment: I edit my post again.

Comment: Can we see a demo of the problem ?

Comment: The *01/01/17* and *01/01/2017* are different formats of date. Does date value really not matter?!

Comment: It's before I submit the form. The plugin autofills the year value to 4 digits which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation, it looks like you should initialize your datepicker with:

```
datePickerController.createDatePicker({
    formElements:{
        'date-picker-id': '%m/%d/%y'
    }
});
```

`%y` is for a 2 digit representation of the year. See [Date formats](http://freqdec.github.io/datePicker/#date-formats) section for details.

Comment: You missed the closing quote. Please, change `'date-picker-id': '%m/%d/%y` to `'date-picker-id': '%m/%d/%y'`.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I want the date format as mm/dd/yyyy, but I don't want the plugin to automatically expand my input year from 2 digits to 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the default behaviour of the datepicker in the `change` event, from the documentation you can use their `addEvent(obj, type, fn)` function, or just stick with the defaule `addEventListener` function.

Your code will be like this:

```
addEvent(datePickerController, "change", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

They provide also an option to remove any event, you can use the `removeEvent(obj, type, fn)` function.